# Having issue while inserting data in influxdb using python client

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python, influx-line-protocol

```
measurement = "measurement"
for column in df.columns:
    for index, value in enumerate(df[column]):
        point = Point(measurement).field(column, value).time(df['unix_time_column'].iloc[index], write_precision="ns")
        write_api.write(bucket="CSV", record=point)
```

The above code block i'm using to insert some value from dataframe to influx bucket.
But whenever I'm adding time the value is not inserting but on the other hand if I remove the time from the it works time.

PS: I check the precision of the also.

Thanks in advance.